# service that run $http for controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple controllers that need to use my custom service which use $http. I did something like this

```
.service('getDB', function($http){
   return {
      fn: function(){

        return $http({
            url: "http://example.com",
            method: "GET"
        });

      }
   }
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, getDB) {
console.log(getDB.fn());
}
```

In my console.log of getDB.fn() I see $promise, how can I get the response data?

Comment: `getDB.fn().success(function(data) {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http returns a promise. Its implementation can be understood here :
[$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q/)

In order to use your promise, you have to do the following :

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, getDB) {
    getDB.fn(something).then(function(result){
         // The result can be accessed here
    }, function(error){
         //If an error happened, you can handle it here
    });
}
```

here is the way you can pass parameters :

```
.service('getDB', function($http){
 return {
   fn: function(something){

    return $http({
        url: "http://example.com/" + something,
        method: "GET"
    });

   }
 }
})
```

Comment: To make even more clear how he 'gets'  the response data by calling `fn()`, maybe add the return statement in the `then(){}` part

Comment: then() is better than success() ?

Comment: Can I pass param to service?

Comment: @AaronMusktin : I've edited my answer. There is no big difference between ``.success()`` and ``.then``. Just use the same everywhere in your app, it will be easier to make it evolve